# Java Servlet Programming with internal server error

Tags: servlets

I am getting an internal server error here.Where is my mistake?
My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Factor extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        int num=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("fact"));
        out.println(num);
        int i,f=1;
        for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
            f=f*i;
        }
        out.println("The factorial is: "+ f);
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exception are you getting? Have you done any debugging to try identifying the problem?

Comment: HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 Factor.doGet(Factor.java:12)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: Well, there you go - it's failing on `Integer.parseInt` - that means the value you're passing to that method (`request.getParameter("fact")`) isn't returning what you expect.

Comment: Then can you please guide me what to do at this stage?

Comment: Step 1: Figure out what value `request.getParameter("fact")` is giving you and why it's doing that. Next steps depend on the results of step 1.